# How to typeset a list of laptop hardware specifications

Tags: tables, graphics

I would like to typeset a nice list of the **basic HW specifications** (CPU, RAM, HDD, etc.). Some of them (CPU,RAM, HDD) would require a list of nested key-value pairs (like Speed-1.8Ghz).

My question is how to create such nice tables as in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E1D7.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYtZg.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygiad.jpg) without having to worry about the typographical (graphical, artistic) side of the thing. Is there any package to do this?

I know there is this [LaTeX Tables wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables), but I am looking for something more suitable and appealing than the bare tables. Also, I would not like to waste the horizontal space. I am using LuaLaTeX with TeX Live 2015.

[image: List 1]
[image: List 2]
[image: List 3]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried (i.e. post your code so far), and let us know which parts are giving you trouble? You will probably get help more quickly that way.

Comment: Which horizontal space don't you want to waste? If columns are aligned and the cells are of different widths, this seems inevitable?

Comment: @IanThompson I admit I have no code yet, but might try something looking at the wiki. I just tried to get some ideas and other solutions before I begin. This problem must have been solved before, after all.

Comment: @cfr I was referring to the fact, that often the key-value pair is too narrow horizontally. For example Speed-2Hgz or integrated-yes. If all (or most) of them are narrow, the table would be narrow and waste the space on the left and right when centered, unless there is a wrapping. However, this is a thesis and wrapping is forbidden. The table must be centered as a figure.

Comment: 4 columns? key - value - other key - other value ?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.